# How to set custom AbstractHealthIndicator as not sensitive in Spring Boot so it shows for /health endpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am running Spring Boot v1.5.2.RELEASE.

How to have `/health` show below without disabling security for entire Spring Boot project?

```
{
    "status": "UP",
    "testing": {
        "status": "UNKNOWN",
        "foo": "bar"
    }
}
```

Here is my code below for TestingHealthIndicator.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health.Builder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestingHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Builder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.withDetail("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

"testing" shows in /health only if i set the following in `application.properties`

```
management.security.enabled=false
management.health.defaults.enabled=false
```

But I do NOT want to disable security for entire project.

I did see some helpful info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html, but did not see a specific way set custom `AbstractHealthIndicator` as non-sensitive.

Comment: Are you using Spring Security together with Actuator?! Is this solved or not?! :)

Comment: I am using Spring Security together with Actuator. Not solved :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you would like to disable Security for healthcheck only. For the rest of the apis, you would like to do the authentication as normal. So, the health needs to show all the information. I used to have the same project in Springboot 4.4. This is what I configured in my application.yml

```
endpoints:
  health: 
    sensitive:  false 

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
  health:
    defaults:
      enabled: true
```

In the security, put the other apis do the fullyAuthentication.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/health access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
```

Hope this help.